# Navbar Center Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been struggling to get my navbar to center using Bootstrap 3, I managed to get the Navbar to center using the navbar-center class and this was working perfectly, but when i view it on a Tablet the last Nav item falls under the DIV, and is seems to be the lefts 50% that creates the problem.

This is my NavBar:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Join SAFEE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for my navbar:

```
.navbar, .dropdown-menu{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
border: none;

}

.nav>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li{
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover,.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  background: none;
}
.navbar a, .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .navbar-toggle{
 color: black;
}
.dropdown-menu{
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow:none;
}

.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+1), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+1){
  border-bottom: #C4E17F 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+2), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+2){
  border-bottom: #F7FDCA 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+3), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+3){
  border-bottom: #FECF71 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+4), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+4){
  border-bottom: #F0776C 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+5), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+5){
  border-bottom: #DB9DBE 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+6), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+6){
  border-bottom: #C49CDE 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+7), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+7){
  border-bottom: #669AE1 3px solid;
}
.nav li:hover:nth-child(8n+8), .nav li.active:nth-child(8n+8){
  border-bottom: #62C2E4 3px solid;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
    color: #fff;
    background: #fff;
}

**@media (min-width: 768px) 
{
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center 
  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
}**
```

I have marked my code that centers in Bold, here is my website that i am testing the Boostrap on http://safee.smudgehost.co.uk/, i just want to center my NAV so it stays in the center regardless of what device it is on, then on mobile it collapses to a Mobile Nav.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the media query? I'd try removing the position, left and transform properties...

Comment: Yeh i was playing around with them and I decided to try with flexbox instead and it worked a dream, and its prefectly centered even when resized.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i managed to fix it in the end.

I added a CSS Class to the container called center-nav and added the following CSS.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

It did the job and works across all screen sizes, thanks for the suggestions :)